# How use Perl to compare two Excel files cell by cell and print any differences

Tags: excel, perl

For example

File 1:

```
Column x:1, 2, 6,…. 
Column y: 21, 2, 5..
```

File 2:

```
Column x: 1, 2, 6…. 
Column y: 21, 2, 1…
```

Output:

```
mismatch in column y, 3rd row
```

Comment: Please show the code that you're having problems with

Comment: You seem to have tagged [tag:java], [tag:php], and [tag:html] by mistake...

Answer (score 1):

Without writing the entire script for you, basically, what you want to do is:

- Open both files.
- Run through each cell and compare it to the cell in the other file.
- If there is a mismatch, push that cell number to an array.
- When the file is done being read, you either say there is no mismatch if the array is empty or you print each element of the array line by line.

I encourage you to try it on your own as that is the best way to learn. If you have any questions, we are more than happy to answer them.

To get you started, here is the command to open the files:

```
open(my $fh1, "<", "excel_file_1.xls") or die "Cannot open excel_file_1.xls: $!";
open(my $fh2, "<", "excel_file_2.xls") or die "Cannot open excel_file_2.xls: $!";
```

Comment: Thanks Kenny Grage for your reply. I am very new to perl and I am not able to code as you said. Please help me out in doing this

Comment: Programming is all about problem solving and figuring things out. I would encourage you to try this problem out in steps. Make two files and have it just read the cell A1 in both files and compare. Once you get that, then branch out. Please try it yourself and let me know where you are getting stuck and I would be glad to help.